# How to include a string variable(char *) within "system" command - linux

Tags: c, linux, grep

char * **S** = "hello";  // assume it's dynamically allocated correctly

I want to use S in the below statement when S would be treated as a string with the value "hello".

system("grep **S** searchtext.txt > result.txt");

How do I do this?

Comment: It's `const char* = "hello";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain C, you traditionally use [snprintf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) to format your command line string into a buffer:

```
char buf[1024];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "grep '%s' searchtext.txt > result.txt", S);
system(buf);
```

Of course, for security reasons, you should never do that if `S` comes from an external source such as a file, a database, or the user himself. That could lead to [shell code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Shell_injection).

Comment: This code is very bad and subject to a classic vulnerability. Consider what happens when the string `S` is `"' ; rm -rf / '"`

Comment: @Eternal Learner, you might want to listen to @R.. Though his answer is more complicated, he's right in the general case :)

Comment: Although not as severe as the code injection, this also fails when S is > ~1000 characters.  `snprintf()` may prevent buffer overflows but can then leave you with vulnerabilities based on string truncation.

Answer (score 8):

In general it's a very very bad idea to use `system` like this. `system` runs the command through the *shell*, meaning that the string you pass to `system` is subject to all of the shell's variable expansion, command expansion, special character interpretation, etc.

If you insist on using `system`, you **must** first sanitize your string. The easiest way to do that is:

```
char *tmp = malloc(4*strlen(S)+3);
tmp[0] = '\'';
for (i=0,j=1; tmp[j]=S[i]; i++, j++)
    if (S[i]=='\'') tmp[++j]='\\', tmp[++j]='\'', tmp[++j]='\'';
tmp[j++] = '\'';
tmp[j++] = 0;
if (snprintf(cmd, sizeof cmd, "foo %s ...", tmp) >= sizeof cmd) goto error;
system(cmd);
```

This code single-quotes the whole string `S` and replaces any embedded single-quotes with `'\''`. Note that I also checked for command line truncation in case it could lead to execution of dangerous commands.

A better alternative would be to abandon `system` entirely and perform your own `fork` and `exec` to bypass the shell. Then there is no command line to be interpreted; you have full control over the arguments (`*argv[]` array) that are passed to the external program.

Comment: Plus if the string is a parameter to "grep" (or any similar command), it's worth adding "--" as the parameter before the string, to stop the string being interpreted as a grep option if it happens to start with a "-".

Answer (score 0):

Well there is system primitive -- execl, execp.
So you can do this `execl("ls", "-la", NULL)` in main.

Comment: You'll probably want to `fork` first unless your program has finished doing everything it wants to do.