# Using self created C variables on linux terminal

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a c program using Linux. But during this time I use the Linux terminal to remove files or copy files and a few other things.

The way I do this is by using a command in c:

```
system ("rm in/file.txt");
```

But what if I want the file Name to be a variable I create in c like:

```
const char *signers[] = {"newfilename.txt"};
```

when I try writing:

```
system ("rm in/signers"); // this does not work obviously since it is all in double quotes. But I can't seem to find the right way to do it
```

Somehow I Need to use this System command along with rm and in/ and then my variable.
I am sorry if this is a Basic question I am a newbie.

Comment: Use unlink system call instead of system

Comment: Yes, please don't. There is a whole bunch of functions in the C library that help you act on files appropriately. `system` isn't one of them.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4291380/694576

Comment: @alk The question you are referring to was asking exclusively for rm commands. I used rm command in my question only as an example to explain my question. This is why I couldnt find the previously asked question as I was searching for a more general answer. However, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a new string that makes up the string you pass to system().

e.g.

```
char command[256];
const char *signers[] = {"newfilename.txt"};

snprintf(command, sizeof command, "rm %s", signers[0]);
printf("Running command '%s'\n", command);
system(command);
```

However there's no need to execute an existing command when you have a C API for it. You can just use the unix specific unlink function:

```
int rc = unlink(signers[0]);
if (rc != 0) {
  perror("unlink failed");
```

or the standard C remove function:

```
int rc = remove(signers[0]);
if (rc != 0) {
  perror("remove failed");
```

Comment: please mention the vulnerability to shell escaping issues with `system`